# Ubuntu Phone -- Problem with on-screen keyboard and a passphrase

Tags: ubuntu-touch, keyboard-layout

I have a BQ Aquaris E5 Ubuntu Edition and I have the following problem.
I have set up a passphrase to lock my phone -- it consists of a few
Latin-1 letters. Then accidentally I have changed in the settings the
keyboard layouts switching off layouts with letters and leaving only
the Emoi layout. Now, I cannot enter my passphrase anymore because the
on-screen keyboard cannot be switched to any layout having letters;
I can only insert Emoi symbols which efficiently means I cannot access
my phone. What should I do?

Best,
Sławek